# Arabic Text (Justified) alignment in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

i am using the iTextSharp .net library to generate PDF files, and the PDF files are generated successfully in Arabic language, but the problem is whenever i set the (HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED) the text is justified but from Left to right not RTL, althogh i have set the RunDirection to be RTL

note: the arabic text is alighned correctly when using (HorizontalAlignment).

appreciate your assistance on this,

regards,